# How to connect Cakephp 1.3 with MS SQLServer 2008?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, cakephp-1.3

I can't connect to MSSQL Server. I've been researching for 2 days, yet I can't find any useful resources. This is the error I'm getting:

> URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.

Help me configure my database. I don't / can't use URL rewriting:

> Your tmp directory is writable.
>   The `FileEngine` is being used for caching. To change the config edit `APP/config/core.php`
>   Your database configuration file is present.

Here's my database config file:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG { 
    var $default = array(
        'driver' => 'mssql',
        'persistent' => false, 
        'host' => 'Charmae-PC\Charmae', 
        'login' => 'sa', 
        'password' => 'pass',
        'database' => 'obbm',
        'prefix' => '',
        'port' => '',
    );
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: is the mssql extension is un-commented on php.ini and test connection is successful ?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the database connection? URL rewriting doesn't have anything to do with the database.

Comment: @elibyy, I uncommented mssql extension but no connection. I realized that latest xampp version 1.7.7 doesnt have php_mssql.dll file which leads me to downgrade to 1.7.3 and did some few tweaks.. Now am able to connect to my database :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your database with cakephp[windows php driver]. I don't know which version cakephp are you using. But for any version of cakephp and wampserver windows php drivers are different.
 for more information 
[Download the sqlsrv driver from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

and then the rest of configuration.

By the way you have to use sqlsrv driver for config/database.php

```
var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
     ...
```