# CakePHP 1.3 - Having problems baking with oracle

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

The comand 'cake bake all' works fine when my database is MySQL, but it fails when I try to generate the mvc code using Oracle.

The application works as expected when the database.php file is modified to use my oracle database after to generate the mvc code using MySQL.

So I believe the oracle isn't the problem.

How can I get 'cake bake all' working when oracle is my default database?

database.php code:

```
 var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'oracle',
    'persistent' => false,
    'login' => 'LOGIN',
    'password' => 'PASSWORD',
    'database' => 'IP:1521/DATABASE'
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You a have to make sure you are using proper database for the cakephp you are using and also supports the version of php and wamp / mamp / lampserver

then start  configuration.
Databases supported by CakePHP
Find list of [Databases supported by CakePHP from here](http://h3rald.com/articles/16/)

Find list of [Drivers from here](http://phplens.com/adodb/supported.databases.html)
and configure it. some thing like here [Configure PHP-sqlsrv Wamp Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624436/how-to-connect-cakephp-1-3-with-ms-sqlserver-2008/16414416#16414416)

Comment: Thanks Isaac! It was a configuration issue. The oracle's driver wasn't enable in php.ini. Once I enable the oracle driver cake console was able to read my oracle database.
The only problem now is that cake is reading not only my user database but the entire oracle database.

Comment: No Problem mate :)!..Happy to hear that. - is your new problem sorted?